# Can we say "passing a function pointer as an argument to a function is called as callback function"?

Tags: pointers, function-pointers

Can we say "passing a function pointer as an argument to a function is called as callback function"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's pretty much the definition of a callback function.

> In computer programming, a callback is
>   a reference to executable code, or a
>   piece of executable code, that is
>   passed as an argument to other code.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_function

Comment: So, if function accepts function pointer as an argument then that is alway called as callback function right?

Comment: The function that is referenced by the pointer you give to the other function is the callback function, not the function that takes the pointer as argument.

Comment: So, Can we put the sentence in this way, "simple function pointer is also called as an implementation of callback function and the function pointer referenced function is called callback function?"